# What is the purpose of setting "this.name = name;" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I'm not exactly sure why this is necessary. If I'm taking in a parameter of "name", why can't it be referenced as "name" without first setting it equal to "this.name"?

Forgive my ignorance, I'm new.

```
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}

Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};
```

Comment: This is not a javascript thing, it's an OOP thing. You want to leave the properties of an object isolated from other properties.

Comment: `name` is a local function argument to `Animal`. It won't be accessible anywhere outside that function. If you want `sayName` to have access to that value, it needs to be stored someplace that is shared between both functions → `this`.

Comment: @deceze Ah that makes sense. I didn't truly understand what "this" was. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.name` represents the instance variable while the `name` variable is a parameter that is in the scope of the function (constructor in this case).

With this assignment, the value of the local variable is assigned to the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a javascript thing, it's an OOP thing. You want to leave the properties of an object isolated from other scopes.

```
var Animal = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};
var name = "foo";
var dog = new Animal("bar");
// shows "foo"
console.log(name);
// shows "bar"
console.log(dog.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

As use of the pronoun “he.” We could have written this: “John is running fast because John is trying to catch the train.” We don’t reuse “John” in this manner, . In a similar graceful manner, in JavaScript, we use the this keyword as a shortcut, a referent; it refers to an object; that is, the subject in context, or the subject of the executing code. Consider this example:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "Penelope",
    lastName: "Barrymore",
    fullName: function ()
        ​// Notice we use "this" just as we used "he" in the example sentence earlier?:​
        console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    ​    // We could have also written this:
        console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... you are working with an object constructor and prototype not just a function with two parameters where example:

```
function Animals(pet1, pet2) {
    var pets = "first pet " + pet1 + " second pet " + pet2;
    console.log(pets);
}
Animals("Tiger", "Lion");
```

so referencing to your parameter as 'this.name' is a prototype of the sayName() if you know what i mean.
[FOR MORE.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp)